# Bootstrap javascript at very end and jQuery $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Much of jQuery depends on `$(document).ready` ... why does bootstrap 2.0 include the javascript library calls at the very end?

Is there a way to get `$(document).ready` to work keeping the js lib calls at the very end?

---

Update: A common example (and the source of my frustration!) is `$("#id").click()`, which does not seem to work if you do not place it inside the `.ready` function...

Answer (score 4):

jQuery only "depends" on `$(document).ready()` to support scripts that are evaluated while the document is still being loaded (e.g. scripts residing in the document's `<head>` or halfway through its `<body>`).

Placing scripts at the end ensures the rest of the document is loaded by the time the scripts are evaluated, so `$(document).ready()` is not necessary in that case.

Comment: Well, after some time fumbling around, I found $('#id').click() does not seem to work if not put outside $(document).ready()... Is there a way to get that to work keeping the old twitter bootstrap js lib order

Comment: @ina, you mean *inside*, not outside, right? That's strange, the `#id` element should be visible to the script unless it occurs after that script on the page. I assume this is not the case?

Comment: hmm so it's a matter of order? is this the right way then: `<div id="id">test</div>` ... lots of other stuff, finally le javascript libraries in footer then `<javascript> $('#id').click(alert('hi')); </javascript>`

Comment: @ina, absolutely, the goal is for the browser to see `<div id="id">test</div>` before `<script>$('#id').click(function() { alert('hi'); });</script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I expect it loads it at the end of the file to improve the performance - see [Yahoo best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Can you put your own JS script tag after the jQuery load?  If you put it after the jQuery load it should work and it should also allow your page to display whilst your code is loaded.